# Using sys.argv to retrieve different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv, sys

So let's say I have these lines of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
if '-h' in sys.argv:
    show_help()
elif '-f' or 'function'in sys.argv:
    print(function1)
elif '-n'or '-name' in sys.argv:
    print(function2)
elif '-e' or '-extension'in sys.argv:
    print(function3])
elif '-m' or '-missing'in sys.argv:
    print(function4)
elif 'r' or '-range' in sys.argv:
    print(function5)
else:
    exit
```

The letters are supposed to be inputs from the user in the bash terminal. 
Showing the help method works and it is able to show all of the strings.
The -f input works and shows the contents that I need in that function, however the code just spits out the content from function 1 and not from function2 and so on.

How do I get these different letters, -f, -n, -e, -m (if inputted) to carry out that function and spit out that information? 
Also is there a more efficient way to do this without using argparse for a beginner Python scripter?

Comment: you check if it is in sys.argv ... and that is true also when you pass -n. Use click for this, relatively simpel compared to argparse

Comment: I recommand the argparse module. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/).

Comment: As a noobie in python I wanted to try something easier. But will give that a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly suggest using **[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)**.

If you prefer not to, creating a dictionary of flags is also possible:

```
flags = {
    '-h': show_help, 
    '-f': function1,
    '-function': function1,
    '-n': function2,
    '-name': function2,
    '-e': function3,
    '-extension': function3,
    '-m': function4,
    '-missing': function4,
    '-r': function5,
    '-range': function5,
}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for flag in sys.argv:
        print(flags[flag])
```

By creating a dictionary, you're able to just look up the keys.

It results in cleaner, faster, and more maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot about creating a dictionary and just using a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

To test if any one of two values is in a list, you can't use the `or` operator with the `in` operator. You need to test each value separately using the `in` operator, like this:

```
if '-h' in sys.argv:
    show_help()
elif '-f' in sys.argv or '-function' in sys.argv:
    print(function1)
elif '-n' in sys.argv or '-name' in sys.argv:
    print(function2)
elif '-e' in sys.argv or '-extension'in sys.argv:
    print(function3])
elif '-m' in sys.argv or '-missing'in sys.argv:
    print(function4)
elif '-r' in sys.argv or '-range' in sys.argv:
    print(function5)
else:
    exit
```

Comment: That's terribly inefficient, at least turn the arguments into a `set` if you're going to do repeated containment checks.

Comment: How would one create a set for repeated checks?

Comment: `set(sys.argv)`

Comment: @zwer you don't need a set, you need a dictionary. It's a much better overall design.